# How to change the temporary upload directory nginx/passenger?

Tags: nginx, debian-lenny, phusion-passenger

When a user uploads `/tmp/stream*` files are created during the upload.

How do I can I change the temporary upload directory from:

```
/tmp
```

to:

```
/home/user/tmp
```

Running:

- nginx 0.8.53
- Phusion Passenger 2.2.15 (mod_rails/mod_rack)
- Debian Lenny

Answer (score 3):

You might want to look at the Nginx upload module.
It lets you ask Nginx to write the file to a folder and then pass a pointer to its location  to your backend. Temporary upload path can be set using $upload_tmp_path variable. Read more at http://www.grid.net.ru/nginx/upload.en.html

Answer (score 3):

If possible at all, you should definitely use Reza's answer and use the 'upload' module.

However, if you use nginx as a reverse proxy with a backend on a different machine, that module won't necessarily do much for you.  To choose where your temporary request bodies (including uploaded files) go, use the 
[client_body_temp_path](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#client_body_temp_path) config option.